# Apply CSS to dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to work out how to call my .each() function with a $(document).ready and a click event, at the moment I have this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".help-inline").each(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

Within a form of mine using nested_form I can clone a field clicking '.example_button' and would like to apply the display:none rule to the newly created element within my DOM.

I have tried this, but obviously the rule is only applied when i click the '.examnple_button'

```
$(document).on('click', '.example_button', function(){
   $(".help-inline").each(function() {
     $(this).css('display', 'none');
   });
});
```

How can i apply the css rules under both circumstance?

Thanks

Comment: On a side note you can skip the `.each` as `.css` does implicit iteration: `$('.help-inline').css('display', 'none')`. `$('.help-inline').hide()` would be even shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the common code out into a function, and call it in both instances.

```
function hideAllTheInlineHelps() {
    $('.help-inline').hide(); // or .css('display', 'none')
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    hideAllTheInlineHelps();
});

$(document).on('click', '.example_button', function() {
    hideAllTheInlineHelps();
});
```

---

### Update

Thanks to @Kartikeya for pointing out that you want the function to run **without clicking the button**.

Looking at [the docs for "nested_form"](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), it seems you can react to the `nested:fieldAdded` event:

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(evt) {
    hideAllTheInlineHelps();
    // or $('.help-inline').hide();
});
```

Comment: The OP wants to hide `.help-inline` without clicking on any `.example_button`

Comment: @Kartikeya Thanks for explaining. First sentence asked how to hide the elements "with a $(document).ready and a click event"! Update should do what OP is after.

Comment: thanks both for your help. Both helped me understand this better..Has made me realise I can just use a pure CSS solution. Hopefully your answers will help someone else out in a similar circumstance

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
$(document).on('focus', '.example_button', function(){
   $(".help-inline").css('display', 'none'); //or $(".help-inline").hide();
});
```

The `.each()` which you are using to iterate `'.help-inline'` is not required ,jquery will automatically iterate all elements with class `help-inline` in DOM.

**OR**

As far i understand your question you are cloning a field clicking `'.example_button'` then one thing you can do is that hide the element when you are creating it otherwise there must be a event on which you want to hide `'.help-inline'` elements,use that event with [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and hide elements with class `'help-inline'` inside DOM.

Comment: Or instead of setting `display: none` just use `$("help-inline").hide();`.

Comment: it now seems as if the .hide() method is not being applied, not even when i click the button

Comment: yes it is a button, you click it and it will generate a new form field, as for the class it is the only one on the page and it is present when the dom loads, the new form field which is generated has a class help-inline, but the .hide() method is not applied to that..does that make sense ? thanks

Comment: and one more thing if you are dynamically adding class help-inline inside DOM then when you are adding  class help-inline there only make its css display none otherwise there must be a event on which you want  class help-inline to be hidden.????..@Richlewis

Comment: you have a very valid point there, which has made me realise I can just use a pure CSS solution, thank you